# Active Record +1 value

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$checkip = Model\Limit::find_by_ip($ip);
if ($checkip) {
$checkip->cnt = +1;
$checkip->save();
}else
{
$limit = new Model\Limit;
$limit->ip = $ip;
$limit->cnt = '1';
$limit->save();
}
```

$checkip->cnt = +1; not working. add +1 to current value

Comment: Is something like `$checkip->cnt += 1;` what you want? The question isn't clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have putted wrong code increment `$checkip->cnt = +1;`.

it should be `$checkip->cnt += 1;`. the `+` sign should  at left and should be attached to `=`.